# Does the Botium-Box automates Account Link flow for Alexa Skill?

Tags: chatbot

We have Alexa Skill for our application which needs account linking.
exploring the botium box for automating conversations, it is working fine.
but I am looking for adding account linking process in it
Is this possible with botium box.. if not, any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You cant link an account using Botium.

The maximum you can do is test your flow using a linked, or not linked account. But you have to link that account on your own, using the Simulator of Actions console for example.

You can read about it here: https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-google-assistant#account-linking